# How to query an element inside an indexed collection using HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Database data:

pkmn_id | pkmn_name

1         | Charmander

These are my entity:

Pokemon.Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pkmn")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NamedQuery(name = "@GET_POKEMON_BY_ID", query = "SELECT pkmn FROM Pokemon as pkmn FireType as ft WHERE pkmn.pkmnID = pkmn.fireAttributes[0]")
public abstract class Pokemon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "pkmn_id")
    private int pkmnID;

    @Column(name = "pkmn_name")
    private String pkmnName;

    public long[] fireAttributes = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

FireType.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pkmn_firetype")
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(value = true)
public class FireType extends Pokemon {

    @Column(name = "fire_immunity")
    private int fireImmunity;

    @Column(name = "fire_attack")
    private int fireAttack;
```

PokemonServlet.class

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query2 = session.getNamedQuery("@GET_POKEMON_BY_ID");
        FireType pk2 = (FireType) query2.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println(pk2.getFireAttack());

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

I have an error in my NamedQuery, the problem is on how I used the array index in the WHERE clause. I'm confused with the right way of including an indexed collection in the WHERE clause.

What is the correct way of implementing this query, wherein the pkmn_id must match the value in the index of an array to retrieve the correct object?

This is my reference
[JBoss Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put comma only. Your query should be as below and use in when you are comparing id with more than one.

```
SELECT pkmn FROM Pokemon as pkmn , FireType as ft WHERE pkmn.pkmnID in pkmn.fireAttributes[0]
```